# Open a PowerPoint presentation from Excel with VBA without specifying Excel file path

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am looking for a way for VBA in PowerPoint to automatically identify the only open Excel file on my computer and use this Excel file to read data from it.  I'd like to avoid having to manually insert Excel file path in my code.  Is it possible?

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("PATH\FILENAME.xlsm")
    xlBook.Application.Visible = False
```

Thank you!

Comment: Look at `GetObject(,"Excel.Application")`

Comment: `CreateObject` *creates* a new Excel instance; if you mean to work with an Excel instance that is already there, you need to use `GetObject` instead ...but should still handle the case where Excel doesn't already have the expected file opened - if your macro intends to work with one specific Excel workbook, then using `GetObject` like this is *assuming* that the expected workbook is opened *and active*: you'll have to validate/assert these assumptions or your code can end up not working against the expected specific workbook/worksheet(s).

Answer (score 2):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testOpenWorkbook()
  Dim Ex As Object, wb As Object
   On Error Resume Next
    Set Ex = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "There is not any Excel session open...", vbInformation, "Ups...": Exit Sub
     Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Ex.Workbooks.count = 1 Then
            Set wb = Ex.Workbooks(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "There are more Excel Workbooks open...", vbInformation, "Ups...": Exit Sub
        End If
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You mixed up If Error and if not statements and there are wrong `Exit For`codes at end of msgbox codelines. `wb`should be defined as `Object` or Excel needs early binding as code will be hosted by Powerpoint. What about using a function and return`wb`(workbook reference).

Comment: @ComputerVersteher: Yes, I intended to use `Exit Sub`. I could swear that this I did... And I had a reference to `Microsoft Excel ... Object Library` and wrote the code with `Dim Ex As Excel.Application`. Then I remembered that some people are afraid of external references and adapted (only) `Ex` declaration... I did not check the code, of course, looking so simple... But thanks! I will adapt the code to be a working one... :). Making a function is not complicated.. But I do not have any feedback, anyhow... I thought that he will start his code with the above one and then he will use `wb`...